# Reordering cells in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView with 10 sections and each section has 3 rows.

Is it possible to reoder the section using the tableViewDelegate methods

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath 
  toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
```

Right now if i am dragging a row from one section and dropping it on another section, its being added to that section. The footer view is also not being selected for reordering, and it remains in the original section.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Since this comes up as one of the first results in Google I thought I'd add the swift code. The Objective-C will is almost the same except for the name of the indexPaths in `moveRowAtIndex`.

**Enable editing mode:**

If you're using a UITableViewController you toggle editing mode with:

```
func toggleEditing() {
    self.editing = !self.editing
}
```

If you're not using a UITableViewController (e.g. you have added a table view to a  UIViewController (or any View Controller other than UITableViewController) then you toggle it with:

```
func toggleEditing() {
    self.editing = !self.editing
}
```

Note: `tableView` is the name of your UITableView.

**Implement canMoveRowAtIndexPath**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool { 
    return true 
}
```

**Implement moveRowAtIndexPath**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   var itemToMove = tableData[fromIndexPath.row]
   tableData.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)
   tableData.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: OP asked Objective-C, the answer should be in objective C, as that is what I am Googling.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this tutorial: [Add, Delete & Reorder UITableView Rows](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/29/iphone-sdk-tutorial-add-delete-reorder-uitableview-row/). There's a working project at the end of the tutorial.

Comment: While links to tutorials are often helpful, the glory of StackOverflow is that the answers are *right here*.  It is common to distill a tute to it's key code bits and leave that as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the candid comment, Olie. While the post is over 3 years old, please feel free to post an answer that provides what you are looking for.